# Multiple File Upload asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, file-upload

is it possible to be able Multiple  select files when make browse file? any solution , may be flash. so on form one field type="file" but with it can be upload more then one file

i know that can be add on form more then one file field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the jQuery plug-in [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which is a neat way of accomplishing this.

> "Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that
>   allows the easy integration of a
>   multiple (or single) file uploads on
>   your website.  It requires Flash and
>   any backend development language.  An
>   array of options allow for full
>   customization for advanced users, but
>   basic implementation is so easy that
>   even coding novices can do it."